# TCP connection/configuration to Event Store issue

Tags: asp.net-core, event-sourcing, eventstoredb

Following this [great book on DDD and event sourcing](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/hands-domain-driven-design-net-core) by Alexey Zimarev, I am going through the code examples, and coding the same concepts on a different domain.
Trying to run the [dockerized example](https://github.com/vladimirvozar-ss/EventSourcingTest/tree/master/EventSourcingTest), with one .NET Core API and Event Store database, I am able to start everything correctly, I go to Event Store UI app, and there I can see that my API managed to initialize the connection to the Event Store:
[image: Event Store UI]

However, when I try to connect to the Event Store from the Controller/Service code, trying to read event stream, I am getting an `"error": "Item Operation ReadEventOperation... reached retries limit : 10 ... "stackTrace": "   at EventStore.ClientAPI.Internal.EventStoreNodeConnection.ReadEventAsync ...`

My appsettings:

```
  "eventStore": {
    "connectionString": "ConnectTo=tcp://admin:changeit@host.docker.internal:1113; DefaultUserCredentials=admin:changeit; HeartBeatTimeout=500"
```

docker-compose.yml eventstore service:

```
    services:
    
      eventstore:
        container_name: esskipass-eventstore
        image: eventstore/eventstore
        command: --dev --enable-external-tcp --ext-ip=0.0.0.0 --int-ip=0.0.0.0 --disable-external-tcp-tls
        environment:
          - EVENTSTORE_CLUSTER_SIZE=1
          - EVENTSTORE_INT_TCP_PORT=1112
          - EVENTSTORE_EXT_TCP_PORT=1113
          - EVENTSTORE_INT_HTTP_PORT=2112
          - EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PORT=2113
          - EVENTSTORE_DEV=true
        ports:
          - "1112:1112"
          - "1113:1113"
          - "2112:2112"
          - "2113:2113"
...
```

and Event Store logs:

```
    ...
[ 1,17,20:59:11.046,INF] External TCP connection accepted: [Normal, "172.20.0.1:54850", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {81629828-c448-49a0-8e99-6fb8803f3928}].

[ 1,21,20:59:12.509,INF] ES "TcpConnection" closed [20:59:12.508: N"172.20.0.1:54850", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {81629828-c448-49a0-8e99-6fb8803f3928}]:Received bytes: 312, Sent bytes: 0

[ 1,21,20:59:12.509,INF] ES "TcpConnection" closed [20:59:12.509: N"172.20.0.1:54850", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {81629828-c448-49a0-8e99-6fb8803f3928}]:Send calls: 0, callbacks: 0

[ 1,21,20:59:12.509,INF] ES "TcpConnection" closed [20:59:12.509: N"172.20.0.1:54850", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {81629828-c448-49a0-8e99-6fb8803f3928}]:Receive calls: 2, callbacks: 2

[ 1,21,20:59:12.509,INF] ES "TcpConnection" closed [20:59:12.509: N"172.20.0.1:54850", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {81629828-c448-49a0-8e99-6fb8803f3928}]:Close reason: [Success] "Socket closed"

[ 1,21,20:59:12.510,INF] Connection '"external-normal"""' ["172.20.0.1:54850", {81629828-c448-49a0-8e99-6fb8803f3928}] closed: Success.

[ 1, 6,20:59:12.511,DBG] Persistent subscription lost connection from "172.20.0.1:54850"

[ 1,21,20:59:12.718,INF] External TCP connection accepted: [Normal, "172.20.0.1:54870", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {45da7e67-2f2b-422b-a1eb-28339c685205}].

[ 1,10,20:59:17.735,DBG] Closing connection '"external-normal"""' ["172.20.0.1:54870", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {45da7e67-2f2b-422b-a1eb-28339c685205}] cleanly." Reason: HEARTBEAT TIMEOUT at msgNum 1"

[ 1,10,20:59:17.735,INF] ES "TcpConnection" closed [20:59:17.735: N"172.20.0.1:54870", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {45da7e67-2f2b-422b-a1eb-28339c685205}]:Received bytes: 312, Sent bytes: 22

[ 1,10,20:59:17.735,INF] ES "TcpConnection" closed [20:59:17.735: N"172.20.0.1:54870", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {45da7e67-2f2b-422b-a1eb-28339c685205}]:Send calls: 1, callbacks: 1

[ 1,10,20:59:17.735,INF] ES "TcpConnection" closed [20:59:17.735: N"172.20.0.1:54870", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {45da7e67-2f2b-422b-a1eb-28339c685205}]:Receive calls: 2, callbacks: 1

[ 1,10,20:59:17.735,INF] ES "TcpConnection" closed [20:59:17.735: N"172.20.0.1:54870", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {45da7e67-2f2b-422b-a1eb-28339c685205}]:Close reason: [Success] "HEARTBEAT TIMEOUT at msgNum 1"

[ 1,10,20:59:17.736,INF] Connection '"external-normal"""' ["172.20.0.1:54870", {45da7e67-2f2b-422b-a1eb-28339c685205}] closed: Success.

[ 1,21,20:59:17.736,DBG] Persistent subscription lost connection from "172.20.0.1:54870"

[ 1, 6,20:59:17.912,INF] External TCP connection accepted: [Normal, "172.20.0.1:54878", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {5c21a809-26be-42b7-b979-b2e6532d508d}].

[ 1,10,20:59:22.926,DBG] Closing connection '"external-normal"""' ["172.20.0.1:54878", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {5c21a809-26be-42b7-b979-b2e6532d508d}] cleanly." Reason: HEARTBEAT TIMEOUT at msgNum 1"

[ 1,10,20:59:22.927,INF] ES "TcpConnection" closed [20:59:22.926: N"172.20.0.1:54878", L"172.20.0.2:1113", {5c21a809-26be-42b7-b979-b2e6532d508d}]:Received bytes: 312, Sent bytes: 22

    ...
```

First I've found out that without `command: --dev --enable-external-tcp --ext-ip=0.0.0.0 --int-ip=0.0.0.0 --disable-external-tcp-tls` my Event Store wouldn't start, TCP port would start disabled. Then I've tried with setting different ports, HeartbeatTimeout, HeartbeatInterval ..., and some other connection settings customizations. Event Store and event sourcing are a new ground to me, so it may be that I am missing some basic customization here.

Appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: Have you tried executing the chapter 11 or 13 code as-is, using the Docker Compose file that I have there? It should work fine.

Comment: I see that you run ES 20.6, that explains...

Comment: Hi @AlexeyZimarev The code from chapter 10 runs fine as-is (the chapter that I've followed). Also, the same code works if I change the docker-compose as you suggested in your answer, with v20.6.1 version, and GitHub packages. I'll go again through the configurations in the code in my example, I must be missing something there ...

Comment: The first patch release (20.6.1) will address many concerns about using ESDB in secure mode and introduces the insecure mode. The insecure mode is not available in the current release.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev I was wrong with my previous comment. The issue is still here if I try with v20 of ESDB. I have also tried to upgrade the Marketplace example from Chapter 10, installed EventStore.Client (20.6.0), docker-compose as from your answer, and it doesn't work. With v5 everything worked fine.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev Definitely, it works fine when used with EventStore.Client (v5.0.9). Do you maybe have some working example, configured with the latest EventStore.Client (v20.6.9)? Or, are there any plans for upgrading Marketplace examples with latest ESDB? Thanks

Comment: As I wrote, 20.6.1 isn't released yet, hence the container tag. The insecure mode isn't available in 20.6.0 at all. It's a matter of a couple of weeks until we release this version, please wait a bit longer. We are upgrading the docs as well, so it will be fine soon. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: The v20.6.1 .NET client should support the insecure mode. It should be available as a preview nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. At the moment, the simplest solution is to use EventStore.Client v5. If not asked for a specific version, the NuGet package manager automatically installs the latest version (v20), it needs to be downgraded to v5. Anyway, docker-compose configurations from your answer work fine with v5 client, but I will leave this answer open for now, until the release of the v20.6.1 client library.

Answer (score 2):

The book code uses the TCP protocol and targets EventStoreDB 5, so you have two choices. The easiest way is to change the image that your compose file uses:

```
image: eventstore/eventstore:release-5.0.8
```

If you want to use v20.6, the easiest way would be to use the 20.6.1 preview in insecure mode:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  eventstore.db:
    image: docker.pkg.github.com/eventstore/eventstore/eventstore:20.6.1-alpha.0.40-buster-slim
    environment:
      - EVENTSTORE_CLUSTER_SIZE=1
      - EVENTSTORE_RUN_PROJECTIONS=All
      - EVENTSTORE_START_STANDARD_PROJECTIONS=true
      - EVENTSTORE_EXT_TCP_PORT=1113
      - EVENTSTORE_EXT_HTTP_PORT=2113
      - EVENTSTORE_INSECURE=true
      - EVENTSTORE_ENABLE_ATOM_PUB_OVER_HTTP=true
    ports:
      - "1113:1113"
      - "2113:2113"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: eventstore-volume-data
        target: /var/lib/eventstore
      - type: volume
        source: eventstore-volume-logs
        target: /var/log/eventstore

volumes:
  eventstore-volume-data:
  eventstore-volume-logs:
```

You would need to login to the GitHub registry once before starting compose. You'd need to get the personal access token in GitHub and then use it as the password for `docker login`. The user name is your GitHub account email.

```
docker login docker.pkg.github.com -u my@email.org -p mytoken
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the code in Chapter 10 working on a locally installed instance (not Docker) with TLS, by using the initialization in Program.cs:

```
var connStr = builder.Configuration["eventStore:connectionString"];
var esConnection = EventStoreConnection.Create(
    connStr,
    ConnectionSettings.Create().DisableServerCertificateValidation().KeepReconnecting(),
    builder.Environment.ApplicationName);
var store = new EsAggregateStore(esConnection);
```

Note the addition of `DisableServerCeritifcateValidation()`.